# SQL: How do you sum he fields in one column, when a separate 2 columns fields are equal

Tags: sql, sql-server

In sql server I am trying add a column to my query that will sum the fields of colC wherever colA and colB show to have a duplicate entry.

Example: I am trying to figure out how much money each person has paid in total.  Each record represents one payment that a person has made.  How do I find the total amount that each person has paid?

My table would look like this:

```
FName | LName  | $Paid
Bob   | Dole   | 1
Bob   | Dole   | 2.2
Bob   | Barker | 6
Bob   | Barker | 2
Bob   | Barker | 2
Herbie| Hancock| 14
```

My desired result would be this:

```
FName  | LName  | $Paid | sum ColC where FName and LName are duplicates
Bob    | Dole   | 1     | 3.2
Bob    | Dole   | 2.2   | 3.2
Bob    | Barker | 6     | 10
Bob    | Barker | 2     | 10
Bob    | Barker | 2     | 10
Herbie | Hancock| 14    | 14
```

The fourth column repetetive outputis not necessary.  This table would also achieve the desired result:

```
FName  | LName   | sum ColC where FName and LName are duplicates
Bob    | Dole    | 3.2
Bob    | Barker  | 10
Herbie | Hancock | 14
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: How Bob Barker got 12?

Comment: Your example data seems to be wrong. Anyway, this is a textbook `SUM`

Comment: oops, now you can see why im so bad at sql, when basic math is this tough...

Comment: You just need to do `SELECT Fname, Lname, SUM(Paid) FROM YourTable GROUP BY Fname, Lname`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it could be solved by reading the documentation of the SUM function, and it's unlikely to help other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can join back on the original table to join the groups back to the original transactions.

```
SELECT
    M.FName,
    M.LName,
    M.total_paid,
    X.SUM(ColC) AS total_paid

FROM
    MyTable M
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            FName,
            LName,
            SUM(ColC) AS total_paid
                    COUNT(ColC) num
        FROM
            MyTable
        GROUP BY
            FName,
            LName 
            HAVING 
                    COUNT(colc) > 1 -- only include places where there are duplicate?
    ) AS x ON X.FName = M.FName and X.LName = M.LName
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT
    FName,
    LName,
    SUM(ColC) AS total_paid
FROM
    whateverTable
GROUP BY
(
    FName,
    LName
);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate that may not be terribly efficient given the distinct keyword, but try this.

```
    CREATE TABLE PAID ( FName VARCHAR(12), LName VARCHAR(12), [$Paid] NUMERIC(10,2))

    INSERT INTO PAID (FName, LName, [$Paid]) VALUES ('Bob','Dole',1);
    INSERT INTO PAID (FName, LName, [$Paid]) VALUES ('Bob','Dole',2.2);
    INSERT INTO PAID (FName, LName, [$Paid]) VALUES ('Bob','Barker',6);
    INSERT INTO PAID (FName, LName, [$Paid]) VALUES ('Bob','Barker',2);
    INSERT INTO PAID (FName, LName, [$Paid]) VALUES ('Bob','Barker',2);
    INSERT INTO PAID (FName, LName, [$Paid]) VALUES ('Herbie','Hancock',14);
```

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        FName,
        LName,
        SUM([$Paid])OVER(PARTITION BY FName + LName) AS total_paid
    FROM
        PAID
    ;
```

Check [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2260/4)